# SQLITE_MISUSE: Database is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite3

Я не понимаю, почему база закрыта, просидел ночь, решил отдохнуть и с новыми силами опять пытаться, но идей уже нет.. [Мой репозиторий](https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/viktor-simanov-instructor-site/src/master/).
Проблема заключается в функции `dateAdd` в `src/models/profile.model.js`, при ней вечно летит ошибка.

```
(node:11200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SQLITE_MISUSE: Database is closed
    at Database.<anonymous> (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:18:25)
    at Database.object.<computed> [as run] (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:28:20)
    at Object.dateAdd (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\src\models\profile.model.js:8:12)
    at dateAdd (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\src\controllers\profile.controller.js:9:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Project\NodeJS\Orders\Viktor-Simanov\instructor-site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Как ее можно вызвать? Запускаем проект `npm run start`, дальше заходим на `127.0.0.1` и пытаемся из левой менюшки перетащить кого-то в календарь.

---

У меня много вопросов по поводу правильности моего использование контроллеров/моделей, я сколько не пытался понять, так и не понял.

Comment: причина: `db.close();` после каждого запроса к бд. об этом явно написано в сообщении об ошибке, в первой строке

Comment: А как правильно тогда? Куда вынести закрытие? Или при завершении процесса всего сервера, она сама закроется и ничего перед этим делать не нужно?

Comment: Я убрал закрытия везде, но теперь мои запросы просто зависают. Кхм, исправил, нужно было текст вернуть еще какой-то.

Comment: для приложения такого уровня сложности я бы вообще не задумывался о ручном закрытии соединения. скорее бы предусмотрел переоткрытие соединения после обрыва. ну и пару раз перечитал бы https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow для расширения кругозора. и, пожалуй, держал бы в голове https://knexjs.org/

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо большое за ссылочки, буду пытаться внедряться).